# RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable == false when running exe within Azure if user is not an Administrator

Tags: .net, azure

I have a Web Role deployed to Azure and as part of the startup process I schedule a .exe to run periodically to perform some background work (a bit [like this](http://devlicio.us/blogs/vinull/archive/2011/10/23/moving-to-azure-worker-roles-for-nothing-and-tasks-for-free.aspx) or [this](http://www.ronaldwidha.net/2011/02/23/cron-job-on-azure-using-scheduled-task-on-a-web-role-to-replace-azure-worker-role-for-background-job/)). This works very well and means I don't need a separate Worker Role which would be relative overkill for what my background task needs to do.

I've been running the scheduled task as a user in the local administrators group but want to tighten that up slightly, but if I take the user out of the local administrators group and run the .exe then `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable` returns false. Is there any good reason for this? What privileges does a user need to be able to get the right value for `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable`?

[Someone had a similar problem here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/269d4698-d234-4fb2-be7e-c8a1a74f03ee) when running a windows service as a non-administrator, but no resolution.

(Also asked on [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/8e48b68f-3e45-43dc-9d7a-c6377275f597))

**UPDATE**: I recently noticed that the [RoleEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.aspx) class documentation says

> The RoleEnvironment class can be used on standalone components in an Azure VM outside of an Azure role. [...] These processes ***must be run with elevated privileges*** to access the RoleEnvironment class.

which is probably the reason my scheduled tasks need to be run using and administrator login.

Comment: That might be some bug in Azure. It's definitely worth trying to use some other local groups instead - maybe you find one that is "tight enough" and still works.

Comment: And your EXE is .NET Console application, right?

Comment: yes, it's a .net console app.

Comment: Are you starting the external EXE from within the webrole's start (in codE) using Process class? you could use processStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add to pass all settings from Role.Environment into the child processes, and read from Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables in those child processes.

Comment: No, I'm using a .bat file during web role startup to create a windows scheduled task to run the exe periodically. For now I'll keep that model and switch to one of the newer Azure features for scheduling tasks when I'm ready to make changes. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I find this indeed frustrating. Are you sure it is just the security group the executing user is in? Do you test this by RDP into the machine, or just waiting from startup tasks. Because if you RDP and you execute something there, it runs in the context of the connected user, and I have never seen any of the RoleEnvironment variables available in my context when I RDP.

However I have a suggestion for you. While a separate worker role might be an overkill, how about just implementing RoleEntryPoint in the same WebRole? It is totally valid and supported scenario. And I've seen number of customers doing so. Just create a public class inside your WebRole which inherits from RoleEntryPoint, override the methods you want (OnStart, OnStop, Run, or even less) and you are done. The only tiny caveat is that if you want a configuration file, web.config won't help. But you have to add WaaIISHost.config file, where you can put all configuration related to the code that runs in RoleEntryPoint.

Now you will have all the context you need, all the configurations you need, all the power you need, and will work in the same Web Role. With better diagnostics, troubleshooting and debugging options then with a Scheduled task.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's related to the security group. I've RDP-ed and changed the scheduled task then waited, and have also tested by changing the startup.cmd to add the user to Administrators or not and then re-deploy.

Comment: When I RDP to the machine and run the .exe myself (logged in as an administrator) I do get the correct value for `RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable` and it's able to use azure to access the cscfg settings just fine. I've never had a problem with that.

Comment: RE `RoleEntryPoint` I'll take a look at that idea, although it would be a more significant change than I want right now since the scheduled tasks is working well other than this issue.